# ntheorem and theoremname

Tags: fonts, theorems

I'm using `ntheorem` (mostly for `thmmarks`), and I'd like to change the font used for the theorem name.  Specifically, I'd like

> `\begin{theorem}[Name of theorem]`

to generate "Theorem 1 (Name of theorem)" with only "Theorem 1" in bold (I think this is the default style in `amsthm`).  Is there any easy way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Name of theorem]
$1 + 1 = 2$.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which theorem-style are you using for the theorems? Please add to your question a minimal, complete and compilable document showing all the settings relevant to this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can modify the plain style as you wish as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%--------------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2 \theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ \normalfont\textcolor{red}{##3}  \theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Name of theorem]
$1 + 1 = 2$.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To produce exactly what the OP wants, I have rewritten it a bit:

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2 \theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ \normalfont({##3})\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[Name of theorem]
$1 + 1 = 2$.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}`

Comment: If `\newtheorem*` (the no numbered version) is to be used with the new style, then `nonumberplain` will also have to be redefined.

Comment: Thanks!  I was hoping for a way to do this without redefining the styles explicitly, but I suppose this is just a limitation of ntheorem.